# Lock a bash script based on parameter?

Tags: bash, shell-script, lock, concurrency

I'm trying to find a way to lock a script based on a parameter given, but was unsuccessful in finding a proper answer.

What I'm trying to achieve is prevent another user from running a script based on some parameter: so if user A executes the script with parameter `JOHN_DOE` (e.g: `-d JOHN_DOE`) and user B executes it with parameter `-d ANNA_DOE` then it runs without any problems, but if user B tries to execute it with `JOHN_DOE` as parameter while the first instance of the script hasn't finished running then it does not allow the user B to run it.

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tool such as `flock` can help manage locks. (It may not work with NFS, depending on whether you believe the documentation or the practice, and similarly may or may not work on SMB or indeed any other remote filesystem.)

The documentation, `man flock`, does have several examples of use. Here's one of them tailored to your scenario.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Example of using flock(1) to provide a named exclusive lock

# Parse command line options
while getopts 'd:' OPT
do
    case "$OPT" in
        d)      lockParam="$OPTARG" ;;
        *)      echo "Usage: ${0##*/} -d <parameter>" >&2; exit 1
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND -1))

# Sanitise lock parameter value (do not trust the user)
lockName="$(printf "%s\n" "${lockParam^^}" | tr -cd '[:alnum:]\n')"
lockFile="/tmp/lock.${##*/}.${lockName:-noname}"

echo "Attempting lock with parameter '$lockParam' sanitised to '$lockName'" >&2
(
    # Get the lock or report failure. See "man flock" for other options
    flock -n 9 || exit 9

    # This section is managed by the exclusive lock. Your program code
    # would go here.
    echo "Achieved exclusive lock on '$lockFile'" >&2

    sleep=10
    echo "Waiting for $sleep second(s) to simulate activity" >&2
    sleep $sleep

    # Exit status 0=ok, otherwise 1-8 is your choice of error codes
    echo "Releasing lock" >&2
    exit 0
    
    # End of exclusive lock section
) 9>"$lockFile"
ss=$?

# Report on exit status from actual code
if [ $ss -eq 9 ]
then
    echo "Failed to acquire lock" >&2
fi

# Exit with meaning
exit $ss
```

Make the script executable (if you call it `lockeg` then `chmod a+x lockeg`), and run it

```
./lockeg -d JOHN_DOE
```

Comment: Yes, I use this technique a lot.  The advantage of using a subshell and locking the file descriptor is that my script doesn't have to explicitly unlock the lockfile.  When the subshell exits, the unlock is automatic.

Comment: This is pretty much what I need, but I am wondering is there any workaround on SIGTSTP (e.g. if user does CTRL+Z  in the shell before finishing the 10seconds and then re-tries this, the lock is still there, so unless removing it manually it will not allow him to execute).

Comment: @classicmusiclover well, yes. If you don't allow the program to end then it hasn't ended. `SIGTSTP` is catchable, if you are really concerned about this possibility

Comment: Why wouldn't it work with NFS? NFS does have a lock manager (NLM).

Comment: @aviro depending on which set of documentation you read, and which OS you're running, `flock` may or may not work over NFS. Note that the question doesn't specifically reference Linux.

Comment: Those documentation [had been out of date for a long time](https://serverfault.com/a/692982/454565), but flock supports NFS since kernel version 2.6.12.

Comment: @aviro a Linux kernel, sure. Can you confirm this for all UNIX operating systems?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "proper" ;-). If you mean "simple" and (relatively) "portable", here you go:

*If* every legal parameter is also a legal filename, you can simply create empty files to use as lockfiles. You must, of course, make sure that there is no gap between creating the lockfile and checking for its existence, but if you have a "proper" shell, you don't need `flock` for that (and there are systems that do not ship with it); you can simply use [`set -C`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) to instruct any Bourne shell to *not* overwrite existing files when redirecting output with `>`.

For example:

```bash
#/bin/sh

# Your paramter.
param="${1?no parameter given}"

# Disallow overwriting files with '>'
set -C

# This will fail if the lockfile exists and create it if it doesn't.
# ':' is a no-op, the output of which is re-directed.
: >"${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$param.lock"

#
# Do stuff ...
#
```

By "proper", I refer to shells that implement `set -C` using the [`open`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) system call's `O_EXCL` flag, which most shells, including the [Bash](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/redir.c#L664), do. Most operating systems, including [Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), guarantee that calls made to `open` with the `O_EXCL` flag set are atomic -- unless the file to be opened resides on a network filesystem.

And if there are legal parameters that are *not* also legal filenames, you can simply hash those.

Comment: Ouch, thanks for catching that. I guess my brain went on auto-pilot after $TMPDIR ;-).

Comment: Yes, it's so easy to do!

Answer (score 0):

You might use a file with users and allowed parameters for each of them, check for user name, and drop out of the script on mismatch.